# I'm looking for a Monero miner written in Java

Tags: mining

I'm looking for a Monero miner written in Java. Can anyone link me one?

Answer (score 1):

I've not come across a Java Monero miner. Closest I can find is a slightly outdated set of JNI bindings for the hash functions: https://github.com/trudly/cryptonight

Honestly though, you're not going to get a miner written in Java coming close to the performance of the existing C/C++ miners, in part due to the fact these do CPU and GPU hashing.

Comment: I thought Monero is a CPU only coin. I don't mind the reduced performance. Thanks for sharing that Github page tho.

Comment: Monero favors commodity hardware (which includes CPUs and GPUs). A miner program that only focuses on one or the other is suboptimal.